# c# - Hide button text when another button is clicked

Tags: c#, button, tags

I'm trying to create a matching game that consists of 12 buttons. The program assigns a random string from an array that has 12 strings in it. When the button is pressed, the tag is passed to the button.text. 
What I'm trying to accomplish now is, for example. If I press "button 1", the text of it changes to "Chevy Camaro". If I press "button 4" next, I want the button1.text to revert back to saying "button 1", rather than it's tag value of "Chevy Camaro". And in like fashion, since  "button 4" was pressed, I would like it to show the tag.....

Each button has similar code to it, besides the button #, which of course changes based on the button that's being used.

I'm unsure how to state that, if button is the current active item, then show it's tag property, otherwise, revert back.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
    button4.Text = button4.Tag.ToString();

    buttoncount++;
    label2.Text = buttoncount.ToString();
}
```

Thanks in advance for all of your help. Slowly learning this stuff.... =p

Comment: You need to make sure all of the buttons use the same event handler. I will type you up an example soon if no one beats me too it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep track of the last button that was clicked:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button lastButton = null;
    int buttoncount;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        button1.Tag = "Ford Mustang";
        button2.Tag = "Ford Focus";
        button3.Tag = "Chevy Malibu";
        button4.Tag = "Chevy Camaro";
        button1.Click += button_Click;
        button2.Click += button_Click;
        button3.Click += button_Click;
        button4.Click += button_Click;
        //etc...
    }

    void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lastButton != null)
        {
            SwitchTagWithText();
        }

        lastButton = sender as Button;
        SwitchTagWithText();

        buttoncount++;
        label2.Text = buttoncount.ToString();
    }

    void SwitchTagWithText()
    {
        string text = lastButton.Text;
        lastButton.Text = lastButton.Tag.ToString();
        lastButton.Tag = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Eric, with the above, if I understand everything correctly, you've statically assigned the string to the corresponding button? I have in place 2 arrays, one for the button name i.e. "button 1", "button 2"..etc. The second array pulls the car names. And it randomly assigns the car names to a random button. The end goal is a matching game. 12 buttons, 6 different car names....etc

Comment: Yes, i was just showing how you can keep track of the button that was clicked...and switch the text back...how you initially fill the tag and text properties is not relevant.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you Eric.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a RadioButton control with its appearance set to button? Replace all buttons with these, put them in a GroupBox and the 'reverting' of appearance when clicked off can be automatically handled. To update the text, a simple event handler like below will do;

```
    private void MakeButton()
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton
        {
            Appearance = Appearance.Button,
            Tag = "Chevy Camero"
        };
        rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged;
    }

    private void rb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton clickedButton = sender as RadioButton;
        string currentText = clickedButton.Text;
        clickedButton.Text = clickedButton.Tag.ToString();
        clickedButton.Tag = currentText;
    }
```

Comment: Requirement for my project states that it needs to be buttons :/

Comment: As in "You MUST use the System.Windows.Forms.Button control"? Otherwise, what I'm suggesting will give every appearance of there being buttons on the screen.